# unable to use ellipsis in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I need to cut a long string and add ellipsis at the end. I read about using `numberOfLines` but it seem to only work on `<Text>` component. I've installed `react-native` package in my reactjs app but when I try to use `<Text>`, it gives an error saying 'Text is not defined'. any solutions?

Comment: Are you just looking for [`text-overflow: ellipsis;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)?

Comment: @David but is there any way to make sure it only create an ellipsis at the end of the second line? because I need a bit of information to be visible and make it as flexible as possible